# How to add a back link?

Tags: javascript, anchor-tags

I am trying to add a 'back a page' link in SharePoint using

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">[Go Back]</a>
```

But as soon as I save the page, it removes the javascript link. Is there another way I should be doing it?

Thanks

Comment: It works with input type, see SteffPoints answer

Comment: Do you know how to use input type as an image instead? See my comment below on SteffPoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately I lately also needed a back button, so I can give you a working solution for it: Just simply add this Code to a Script Editor Web Part or Content Editor Web Part on the Site where u want it.

```
<input type="button" value="back" onclick="window.history.back()"
 style="color: white; background-color:rgb(196, 196, 196); 
font: 15px arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, Ive tried modifying use a image instead, but it wont go back a page now. Please can you check my code?   'code' <input type="image" src="/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/PublishingImages/addaproduct.png" onclick="window.history.back()"/> 'code'

Comment: I would rather define your image as background of the button. Add the following CSS within the tag: style="background: url(myimage.png)"

Comment: Thankyou, all working now!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below mentioned steps :

- Write your code in a text file.
- upload it to any library.
- Now open your webpart page in edit mode
- Add Content Editor wbpart
- go to webpart setting.
- set path for the txt file uploaded in library
- click ok and you are all set

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1);" id="btBack">Back</button>`